# Insert X, Y, and Z labels for 3D Graph in latex (overleaf)

Tags: labels, 3d, overleaf

I tried to insert X, Y, and Z labels into the 3-D graph, but I cannot.

My Latex codes (I use Overleaf) are like that. Please help me.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]

\caption[Caption for LOF]{The Plot of Probability of X, Y and Z \textsuperscript{(*)}}

\centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{graph_file_name}

\small \textsuperscript{(*)The 3-D Graph}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: What is the content of `graph_file_name`?

Comment: Can't you just edit the image, or add the labels in whatever software you used to make the figure?

Comment: no I cannot unfortunately. @TorbjørnT.

Comment: graph files's name that I import. @marmot

Comment: TikZ is a bit overkill, but you could use this technique: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz `\node at (x,y) {text};` can be used to add text.